# ui-route parameter $location.path

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Anyone tried to change view via $location.path with ui-route, but with a parameter?

I'm trying to do that but it doesn't work.  I think it's from my app.js routes definition that doesn't work

What I want is when I change to 'show-instance' (always with an id), I'm redirected to  editing-instance.html.

controller.js

```
.saveShow($scope.spectacle)
        .then(function (data) {
            if ($scope.spectacle.ShowId === null) {
                $location.path('show-instance/' + data);
            }
            else {
                $location.path('listing-shows');
            }
        })
```

And in my app.js

```
$stateProvider.state('show-instance', {
    url: '/show/instance/:eventId',
    templateUrl: 'show/editing-instance/editing-instance.html'
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `$location`, use the `$state` provider that comes with UI Router:

```
$state.go("show-instance", {
       eventId: "123"
});
```

Comment: @sma i need to reload the page after redirecting to page. how to do it in ui-router. i have already tried `$state.go('dashboard.places.list', {}, { reload: true});` it is redirecting to the particular view , but not reloads

Answer (score 0):

$state.go is the optimum approach while using ui.router. However if you need to use $location, then do not use the state name to transition. Use url instead. 
 `$location.path('/show/instance/data')`